# ASP.NET MVC - JSON + HttpException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return an error page indicating that the user couldnt be found and therefore I throw a HttpException with status code 404, however for some reason it wont redirect to the error page? - Is there some sort of trick to handle error pages with JSON that I should be aware of?

My current code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    User userToGet = _session.Query(new GetUserById(id));

    if(userToGet == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "User not found");
    }

    DetailsUserViewModel userToViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User, DetailsUserViewModel>(userToGet);

    return Json(new
    {
        HTML = RenderPartialViewToString("Partials/Details", userToViewModel)
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update - Some more code:**

// MyJs.js

```
function openBox(object) {
    $("body").append("<div id='fadeBox'></div><div id='overlay' style='display:none;'></div>");
    $("#fadeBox").html("<div style='position:absolute;top:0;right:0;margin-right:2px;margin-top:2px;'><a id='closeBox' href='#'>x</a></div>" + object["HTML"])
    $("#fadeBox").fadeIn("slow");
    $('#wrapper').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#overlay").show();
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#mybox') /* Enable client-side validation for partial view */
}
```

// List.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyDemon.ViewModels.ListUsersViewModel>

<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
        <td>UserId</td>
        <td>UserName</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.UserId</td>
            <td>@user.UserName</td>
            <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "details", "account", new { id = @user.UserId }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", OnSuccess = "openBox" })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by redirect to the error page?  Wgat are you actually getting?  If this is AJAX, you need to handle the error ib your AJAX call, by design it won't change the browser's address.

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't redirect"? What happens? Does it display the same as if no exception had occurred? Or does it show some error message?

Comment: @Codo, nothing happens.. it just remains in the same state as before the exception occured... Think @Jason Goematt is right about that its against the behaviour of AJAX to interact with the clients browser address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller action is very strange. You are returning a JSON object but which contains HTML. That's not necessary. If you intend to return HTML then return a partial view. JSON brings no value in your situation:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    User userToGet = _session.Query(new GetUserById(id));

    if(userToGet == null)
    {
        return PartialView("404");
    }

    DetailsUserViewModel userToViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User, DetailsUserViewModel>(userToGet);

    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Partials/Details.ascx", userToViewModel);
}
```

If you want to use JSON then work with objects:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    User userToGet = _session.Query(new GetUserById(id));

    if(userToGet == null)
    {
        return Json(new { user = null }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    DetailsUserViewModel userToViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User, DetailsUserViewModel>(userToGet);

    return Json(new { user = userToViewModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then:

```
$.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("Details") %>', { id: '123' }, function(result) {
    if (result.user == null) {
        alert('user not found');
    } else {
        // do something with result.user
    }
});
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, the reason for returning a json object with HTML is that it needs to render the partialView and inject the needed model into it, since the partialView will render inside a box that will overlap the current content. Short: I'm returning HTML with the json object since it'll be used in a javascript function that will render an object with the content of the partialView.

Comment: @ebb, when you return partial HTML from your controller action you could inject it wherever you want in the DOM in the success callback. I don't see what's the problem.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - check update. The reason for returning the HTML from the controller is that I'll only need 1 function in my javascript section, which will render the object that contains the HTML.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, do you think its bad design to let the controller render the nessecary PartialView to a string, instead of creating a javascript function for each actionresult that will return a custom JSON object?

Comment: @ebb, yes, I think it is a bad design to have the controller render some view as HTML string just to return it back to the view as JSON object property when you could directly return the HTML as outlined in my answer.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, correct me if I'm wrong... I'll need a javascript function for each of those actionresults then?

Comment: @ebb, I wouldn't use `Ajax.ActionLink` helpers to generate my links. I would use a simple `Html.ActionLink` which I would then AJAXify in an external javascript file using jquery.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Do you mind showing an example of how to AJAXify a Html.ActionLink in an external javascript file using jquery?

Comment: @ebb, like this: `$('#linkId').click(function() { $('#resultDiv').load(this.href); return false; });` where `resultDiv` is the id of a `<div>` which will harbor the partial HTML returned by the controller action this link is pointing to.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - I see... Just to clarify a few things. The reason for not rendering the partialView in the controller and return it as HTML is that its bad design, and will most likely be a mess to maintain later right? - Also the reason for using @Html.ActioLink instead is to reduce noise in the HTML code? Also you said in your previous comment "...is the id of a <div> which will harbor the partial HTML returned by the controller action this link is pointing to" - I guess you meant the JSON object returned by the controller action?

Comment: @ebb, the reason for it being a bad design is because you are mixing JSON and HTML. Concerning the `Html.ActionLink` I prefer it because it gives me more control over the AJAX request and not because of the noise (the noise have been reduced in ASP.NET MVC 3 thanks to the unobtrusive ajax). And finally about the `<div>`, my comment applies only if your controller action returns HTML. If you return a JSON object you will have to parse it on the client side and decide what to do with it, you cannot put a JSON object into a div it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: "And finally about the <div>, my comment applies only if your controller action returns HTML..." <= We're talking about what I was trying to do in the start right? - since I shouldnt mix HTML and JSON.

Comment: @ebb, in your original code you weren't returning HTML. You were returning JSON containing HTML which is not the same. In my answer I suggested you two approaches: either use HTML or use JSON but don't mix both. And the example I provided with AJAXifying the link applies only if you return HTML.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - ah, thanks :=) - Just a last question: Do you mind to show an example of how the Html.ActionLink would look like if it was suppose to work with ajax? I've been trying different approaches like @Html.ActionLink("details", new { @class = "displayUserDetails" @id = @user.UserId }) - but without luck.

Comment: My two cents. I also return HTML in the Json response, but I add a success variable:  return Json(new { success=1, user = userToViewModel }); or return Json(new { success=0, message="Something went wrong" }); That way my script can handle the errors or insert the html when all goes wel.

Comment: @ebb, it would look like this: `@Html.ActionLink("More details", "details", new { id = user.UserId }, new { @class = "displayUserDetails" })` which would render as `<a class="displayUserDetails" href="/Home/details/123">More details</a>`. You could also add an unique id attribute to the anchor along with the class if you want to perform id selectors in jquery, but a class selector works as well, it's just that it would apply to all links having this class.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - hmm.. it just tries to navigate to the URL instead of using the javascript function.

Comment: @ebb, and how, where did you attach the javascript function? Are there any javascript errors popping up in the FireBug console? Did you `return false;` in your `click` handler to prevent the default action?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - ah!, forgot the return false; - I wont bother you anymore - Thank you for your help and time! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually @Darin Dimitrov ... - I'll bother you once again ;8 - In your first code example where you use return partialview() - how would you check whether it's returning a 404 partialview or the details partialview in the javascript function?